# How to write proguard for gcm and gcm server

Tags: android, proguard

I am using gcm server for push notification in my application. But I dont know how to write proguard for gcm, Somebody Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use GCM (gcm.jar SHA1:a6d7bce795a14c7f86111756c4ceb44b79de14aa) in my app with proguard. I did not have to write a special proguard configuration. Do you have any errors when obfuscating or running the app?

Comment: Warning: com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender: can't find referenced class org.json.simple.JSONValue

Comment: the problem is that you are using json simple use -libraryjars /lib/json_simple-1.1.jar  (where you put your own name of the library)